# What is the git commands to delete unwanted commits that haven't been pushed to the remote?

Tags: git, branch, local, commit

If I have a few local topic branches I have made commits on and haven't yet pushed them to the remote, how can I delete them?

I don't want to pollute the main tree with unwanted commits.

Comment: You can keep them local and not push them.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't yet pushed them to the remote, it should be easy to delete them.

```
git branch -D <branch-to-delete>
```

will forcibly delete a branch that you don't want to keep.

Comment: Is it possible to do that for individual commits as well?

Comment: Yes to individual commits: See this question's answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669063/pushing-just-one-revision-to-git-repository/3669209#comment3863646_3669209.

Comment: Just to be pedantic: deleting a branch deletes the tag that represents the branch and leaves the commits that are pointed to at their HEAD by that branch as dangling, prone to be cleaned up in the next garbage collection sweep, but it doesn't actually *delete* those commits.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking up rebase- there is a good series of videos here: http://www.ava.co.uk/git

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. This way it's possible to drop single commit. I assume the commit you want to drop is no further than 16 steps back from the HEAD.

`git rebase -i HEAD~16...HEAD`